# Binding not Updating after Invoking PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm developing some kind of time tracking application.

[image]

The model looks like this:

> My DataGrid is bound to `ObservableCollection<Entry>`:

```
public class Entry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string TicketId {get; set;} //Simplified since working..

    private ObservableCollection<TimeBooking> _timebookings;
    public ObservableCollection<TimeBooking> TimeBookings
    {  
        get { return _timebookings; }
        set
        {
            _timebookings = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public TimeBooking Monday //Same for other days...
    {
        get
        {
            return Bookings.Where(b => b.Date == SelectedWeek.FirstDay);
        }
    } 
}
```

TimeBooking looks like this:

```
public class TimeBooking : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TimeBooking(DateTime date)
    {
        Date = date.Date;           
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    private TimeSpan _value;
    public TimeSpan Value
    {        
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _changed;
    public bool Changed         //CHANGED SETTER IS INVOKED BY CELL CONTEXT MENU
    {
        get { return _changed; }
        set
        {
            _changed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

}
```

The Issue is in here:

```
 <DataGrid.CellStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource EditedConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Pink" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource EditedConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Lime" />
             </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
         <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}" />
     </Style>
 </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

This is my Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridCell dgc = value as DataGridCell;
        if(dgc != null)
        {
            ENTRY entry = dgc.DataContext as _ENTRY;
            if(entry != null)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn column = dgc.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
                if(column != null)
                {
                    var binding = column.Binding as Binding;
                    if(binding != null && binding.Path != null && binding.Path.Path != null)
                    {
                        string val = binding.Path.Path.ToLower();
                        if (val.StartsWith("monday"))
                        {
                            return entry.monday.Changed;
                        }
                        if (val.StartsWith("tuesday"))
                        {
                            return entry.tuesday.Changed;
                        }
                        if (val.StartsWith("wednesday"))
                        {
                            return entry.wednesday.Changed;
                        }
                        if (val.StartsWith("thursday"))
                        {
                            return entry.thursday.Changed;
                        }
                        if (val.StartsWith("friday"))
                        {
                            return entry.friday.Changed;
                        }
                        if (val.StartsWith("saturday"))
                        {
                            return entry.saturday.Changed;
                        }
                        if (val.StartsWith("sunday"))
                        {
                            return entry.sunday.Changed;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As we see the `Binding` to `Changed` is working (Foreground is Lime) but somehow changes to that property are not noticed..

Comment: shouldn't it be `OnPropertyChanged("Changed");` ? you are not passing property name

Comment: I'm using this signature: `OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)`

Comment: @Felix, there is *no* binding to `Changed` in your xaml. `Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` *won't* listen to viewmodel changes

Comment: @ASh right.. I will add my Converter just a sec.

Comment: @FelixD. The converter is irrelevant. There is nothing that listens to the PropertyChanged fired from the Changed setter.

Comment: Maybe this approach is complete garbage... All i want is to hightligt the cells which have been edited..

Comment: So why is the `Lime` foreground set then ?!

Comment: That's evaluated once. Initial evaluation of a binding source/path is a different thing than listening for property changes.

Comment: Any idea on how I could bind to that ?

Comment: I need something like `SelectedCell.TimeBookings.Any(b => b.Changed == true)` in my binding **BUT** only for that day the cell is in the column

Comment: Why don't you bind to the Changed property?

Comment: Because the actual item is Entry and in Need to bind on one of the TimeBookings.Changed in that specific entry

Comment: But you need to invoke the converter whenever the Changed property is set to a new value, right?

Comment: Honestly im not even sure if i need the converter at all. I just need to highlight changes on a specific day on any of the TimeBookings.

Comment: You could try to use a MultiBinding. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your converter to be invoked whenever the `Changed` property is set to a new value, you could use a a `MultiBinding` and a multi converter (implement `IMultiValueConverter`):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Pink" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="false">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Changed" />
                    <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Lime" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CellContextMenu}" />
</Style>
```

---

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    DataGridCell dgc = values[1] as DataGridCell;
    if (dgc != null)
    {
        ENTRY entry = dgc.DataContext as _ENTRY;
        if (entry != null)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = dgc.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
            if (column != null)
            {
                var binding = column.Binding as Binding;
                if (binding != null && binding.Path != null && binding.Path.Path != null)
                {
                    string val = binding.Path.Path.ToLower();
                    if (val.StartsWith("monday"))
                    {
                        return entry.monday.Changed;
                    }
                    if (val.StartsWith("tuesday"))
                    {
                        return entry.tuesday.Changed;
                    }
                    if (val.StartsWith("wednesday"))
                    {
                        return entry.wednesday.Changed;
                    }
                    if (val.StartsWith("thursday"))
                    {
                        return entry.thursday.Changed;
                    }
                    if (val.StartsWith("friday"))
                    {
                        return entry.friday.Changed;
                    }
                    if (val.StartsWith("saturday"))
                    {
                        return entry.saturday.Changed;
                    }
                    if (val.StartsWith("sunday"))
                    {
                        return entry.sunday.Changed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Sadly this is not working ;( `System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Changed' property not found on 'object' ''ENTRY'` Since the DataContext ( `.` ) is `Entry` - the Converter returns `Changed(bool)`

Comment: I though your DataGrid was bound to the TimeBookings collection. Maybe you could post your full code if you want anyone to be able to help you?

Comment: I thought I put everything relevant there... `ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"` which is an ObservableCollection of `Entry`. - **Sorry** for the obviously bad question :/

Comment: Then I don't understand how you set the Changed property. You should move this property to the Entry class. You are indeed changing the entry.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing you converter, I can tell you that the reason you are not getting the Converter triggered on data change is because you are binding to the Control, which does not get changed you when change a value from one of it`s properties.

To be able to achieve what you want, you have to either do a cumulative property inside you datacontext viewmodel, and bind the trigger to that, or some other way.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
   public ObservableCollection<TimeBooking> TimeBookings
{  
    get { return _timebookings; }
    set
    {
        _timebookings = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TimeBookings");
    }
}
```

And so on.

Comment: This won't help. First I don't change the collection itself. 2. ObservabeCollection already handle changes to containing objects...